# Change attribute text and keep value of an input with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Sorry my English...is not very good but i will try to explain my problem. I got a form with some input fields that has to show values in currency format, but the attribute "value" of the field has to be in type float. Resuming: I want that the input shows his value in currency format, but withou changing his float value.
I'm using Knockout to do the bindings of the values.
Above one of my attempts:
Html code:

```
    <input data-bind="value: unit_price, attr:{text: $parent.currency($data.unit_price())}" type="text" name="unit_price" class="align_right unit_price_col" />
```

Knockout:

```
    self.currency = ko.computed({
         read: function(key) {
    },
     write: function(value) {
         console.log(value); // Value of the input
     }
    });
```

My attempt was trying to create a computed function that when the value was changed, the function receive that value, format the value to currency, and only change the attribute text to show the formatted value, without changing the value of the observable.
Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The computed hides the real observable, only solution with current version of KO is to expose the value like

http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3f8/

```
ko.extenders.currency = function(observable, options) {
    var wrapped = ko.computed({
        write: observable,
        read: function() {
            return Globalize.format(observable(), "c" );
        }
    });

    wrapped.raw = observable;
    return wrapped;
};
```

I have suggested to the KO team that they should introduced a third function `format`
Which is used by the bindnigHandlers, this way your observable always return the real value but the View uses the formated value. Until then this is one way of doing it

**update:** 
If you want to update the value from a input with the value binding then you need to get a little more creative since it will be a string

http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3f8/1/